# Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity API without Visual Studio

Tags: .net, windows-ce, smart-device

I was wondering if it is possible to use the Microsoft smart device APIs without installing visual studio? If so how can I deploy it? How I can overcome the following exception:

```
    Exception: Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DatastoreException: Retrieving 
    the COM class factory for component with CLSID {74AD2302-A606-428E-B40F-
    F04B8964ADB6} failed due to the following error: 80040154.     
    at Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DatastoreManager..ctor(Int32 localeId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the Microsoft smart device APIs without
>   installing visual studio?

**No. It's not possible.**